# I have these .html files on github and I wasnt to open them in sublime text 3. how do I do so? Can I please get step by step instructions

Tags: html

[image: Screenshot of GitHub repository, showing two .html files; title "HTML, CSS, and Javascript for Web Developers example code"]

Here are the files on GitHub attached, and I want to know how to open them in Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Have you tried downloading them?

Answer (score 1):

If it’s just a single file, you can go to your GitHub repo, find the file in question, click on it, and then click `View Raw` or `Download` at the top of the file preview to obtain a raw/downloaded copy of the file and then manually open it with sublime on your computer.

Comment: @mudafar-malkawi can you mark this as answered if this resolved your query?

Answer (score 0):

You can [clone the repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository-from-github/cloning-a-repository) to your disk and then simply open them like you would any file.